# Change of the average when a number is removed

Tags: arithmetic

The average of 21 members is 30. The largest number is 50. If we remove the largest number then the average of remaining numbers will be?

Comment: Try calculating the sum of all the numbers, and then, the sum of the remaining numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. In order for us to help you, it helps for you to give us an idea of what you've tried to far - that way we can tailor advice to your knowledge level

Comment: If the average out of $21$ members is $30$, the sum is $630$. When you remove the member with $50$, you have $20$ members whose sum is $580$, hence the average drops to $29$.

Comment: I guess that comment can go as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

The sum of the thirty numbers is $n \cdot \overline x= \color{blue}{21}  \cdot \overline x$, where $\overline x$ is the average of the thirty numbers.

Edit: blue printed have been edited.

Then subtract the largest number from the result. After that, divide the new result by (n-1).