# Finding mean from remaining value

Tags: statistics, means

The average property of $123$ non soldier sons was $14905.69$. The average property of $14$ soldier sons was $17678.57$. If one of the soldier sons had no property at all, **what is the mean property value of the remaining $13$ soldier sons?**

Comment: Duplicate of [Change of the average when a number is removed](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/875120).

Answer (score 3):

The total value of the 14 soldier sons property would be 247,499.98 since $\frac{247,499.98}{14} = 17,678.57$ by definition of the mean. If one of the soldier sons has zero property and we eliminate this soldier son, then the total property value remains 247,499.98. In this case, the mean property value of the remaining 13 soldier sons would be $\frac{247,499.98}{13} = 19,038.46$.